# How to use swig with compiled dll and header file only

Tags: python, c++, dll, wrapper, swig

I have read some docs from [SWIG documentation](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/SWIGPlus.html) (related to c++ code), but can't figure out if it is possible to genereate Python extension module in case I have *compiled dll* (no source code provided) and *header file* with all functions declared in dll.

If someone has the same problem and solve it, could you provide some useful example?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.  SWIG only uses the headers to generate wrapper functions. Here's a simple SWIG file:

```
%module mymod
%{
#include "myheader.h"
%}

%include "myheader.h"
```

Then:

```
swig -python -c++ mymod.i
```

Then compile and link the generated code as a Python extension DLL.  You will also need to link in the .lib for the wrapped DLL.

Comment: The same approach works for C# as well. I suppose this will work for other languages too.